# ZFS silently overwrites the later mirrored devs, without any logs?

Tags: zfs, zpool, openzfs

Given two mirrored drives:

- `/dev/loop1` of `zfs1.img`
- `/dev/loop2` of `zfs2.img`

If the drives contain different data, even if the copies in `zfs2.img` are **newer**, or `zfs2.img` contains **extra files**, ZFS always silently uses state of `zfs1.img`, and **overwrites** all files in `zfs2.img`.

In these situations, the most favourable behaviour would be to list out all the conflicting copies and let the user (or administrator) decide.

ZFS is designed to be a smart filesystem that perform automatic recovery with minimal user interference. However, ZFS should at least leave a log of its actions, especially when it decides to delete a file. I have searched extensively but found no mention of such a log.

Step to reproduce:

1. Create a simple mirror.
2. Write a common file to both drives, then export.
3. Unmount `zfs2.img`; import with only `zfs1.img`, modify the common file, write a new file one, export.
4. Mount `zfs2.img`, unmount `zfs1.img`; import with only `zfs2.img`, modify the common file, write a new file two, export.

At this stage:

- `zfs1.img` contains its own version of the common file, and the new file one.
- `zfs2.img` contains its own version of the common file, and the new file two. The version of the common file in `zfs2.img` is newer. `zfs2.img` also contains an extra new file two.

Continuing with the reproduction:

5. Mount `zfs1.img`; import with both `zfs1.img` and `zfs2.img` mounted, note that the version and files of `zfs1.img` are shown in the filesystem. The version and files of `zfs2.img` is not available. Export.
6. Mount `zfs2.img`, unmount `zfs1.img`; import with only `zfs2.img`, note that the version and the new file two in **`zfs2.img` are silently overwritten**. Export.

The issue is now reproduced. Even though the version in `zfs2.img` is newer and there is a newer file in `zfs2.img`, both are overwritten without any error messages.

I am still unable to find any logs mentioning this issue.

Additional step: If the first drive is replaced with a blank drive, ZFS does not overwrite drive two with the blank drive one, as normally expected. Instead, the blank drive one is populated with the data from drive two:

7. Create a new blank drive, import, replace missing drive one with the newly created drive. Export.

Code to reproduce:

(1) Create a simple mirror.

```
print_status() {
printf -- 'vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv\n'
ls -Al /zpool_test/ ; cat /zpool_test/* ; echo ; losetup ; zpool list -v ; zpool status -v
printf -- '^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n'
}

printf '(1) : Create mirror\n'
tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)
cd "${tmpdir}"
truncate -s 100M "${tmpdir}/zfs1.img"
truncate -s 100M "${tmpdir}/zfs2.img"
loop1=$(losetup -f --show "${tmpdir}/zfs1.img")
loop2=$(losetup -f --show "${tmpdir}/zfs2.img")

/sbin/modprobe zfs

zpool create zpool_test mirror "${loop1}" "${loop2}"
```

(2) Write the common file to both drives.

```
printf '(2) : Write common to both\n'
echo 'common' > /zpool_test/file_common
print_status
zpool export zpool_test
```

(3) Only in drive one: Modify the common file & Add a new file one.

```
printf '(3) : Modify & Add only to one\n'
losetup -d "${loop2}"
zpool import zpool_test
echo 'append one' >> /zpool_test/file_common
echo 'new one' > /zpool_test/file_new_1
print_status
zpool export zpool_test
```

(4) Only in drive two: Modify the common file & Add a new file two.

```
printf '(4) : Modify & Add only to two\n'
loop2=$(losetup -f --show "${tmpdir}/zfs2.img")
losetup -d "${loop1}"
zpool import zpool_test
echo 'append two' >> /zpool_test/file_common
echo 'new two' > /zpool_test/file_new_2
print_status
zpool export zpool_test
```

(5) Import both. Shows only the version and files in `zfs1.img`.

```
printf '(5) : import both one and two\n'
loop1=$(losetup -f --show "${tmpdir}/zfs1.img")
zpool import zpool_test
print_status
zpool export zpool_test
```

(6) Import only two. Check `zfs2.img` is overwritten silently without any logs.

```
printf '(6) : import only two\n'
losetup -d "${loop1}"
zpool import zpool_test
print_status
zpool export zpool_test
```

(7) If drive one is replaced with blank drive, blank drive is overwritten.

```
printf '(7) : if one is replaced with blank\n'
truncate -s 100M "${tmpdir}/zfs_new_1.img"
loop4=$(losetup --show /dev/loop4 "${tmpdir}/zfs_new_1.img")
zpool import zpool_test
zpool replace zpool_test /dev/loop1 /dev/loop4
sleep 1
print_status
zpool export zpool_test
```

Last but not least, handy clean up script is also provided:

```
zpool import zpool_test
zpool destroy zpool_test
# losetup -d "${loop1}" "${loop2}"
losetup -d "${loop2}" "${loop4}"
rm -rf "${tmpdir}"
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this experiment? What relevance does it have to a production or business use case?

Comment: *In these situations, the most favourable behaviour ...*  According to who?

Comment: In case there is a read error of a file in disk one, will the corresponding file in disk two being silently deleted? In the above example, `file_new_2` was silently deleted because it is not available in disk one. If yes, mirroring (or RAID) only protect against disk errors in later disks, but not the first disk. This is clearly not the aim of mirror or RAID.